# Trouble installing Bluetooth driver on M14xR2 running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, regedit, windows-defender

I'm trying to install the Bluetooth Driver found here: [dell.com](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/hncv9w1/drivers)
I'm using the 8.1 network driver. When I try to install it I get the following error

```
Could not write value C:\Program Files(x86)\Intel\Bluetooth\  to key \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths
```

and

```
Could not create key: \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths
```

I've already tried disableing Windows Defender and that still does nothing, I've also tried adding a exeception to the file and that still doesn't work.

Comment: A driver written for 8.1 will not work in windows 10. Windows 10 has a completely new driver model and most drivers for previous windows versions will not work.

Comment: @Moab I'll look into finding a driver for the same device although i'm not certain one exists, If not there may be a workaround as some drivers written for windows 8.1 may work for windows 10.